# LaTex Tikz: State chart arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to create this state chart in tikpiz but having problems with the arrows on the side C5, C6, C7. I would like to bend C8 and C10 if possible, Do you have any advise?

Reference image:

[image]

My current attempt:

[image]

Please see my latex code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!tb]    
%\raggedleft
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
    \footnotesize

[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto,initial text=, every state/.style={rectangle, width=5cm, minimum height=0.8cm}, every link/.style {thick, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt}]



\node[align=center]  (E) at (0,0)   [rectangle,draw,text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]    {Enrolment};

\node[align=center]  (F) at (0,-2)  [rectangle,draw,text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]     {First year};

\node[align=center]  (S) at (0,-4) [rectangle,draw,text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]     {Second year};

\node[align=center] (A) at (6,-4)  [rectangle,draw,text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]    {Attrition};

\node[align=center] (T) at (0,-6)  [rectangle,draw,text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]     {Third year};

\node[align=center]  (G) at (0,-8) [rectangle,draw,text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]    {Graduate};



\path[->]

(E) edge (F)

(E) -- (F) node[midway, circle, draw,fill=white!20] {?}

(F) edge (S)

(F) -- (S) node[midway, circle, draw,fill=white!20] {?}

(S) edge (T)

(S) -- (T) node[midway, circle, draw,fill=white!20] {?}

(T) edge (G)

(T) -- (G) node[midway, circle, draw,fill=white!20] {?}

(S) edge (A)

(S) -- (A) node[midway, circle, draw,fill=white!20] {?}

(F.east) edge (A.north)

(F.east) -- (A.north) node[midway, circle, draw,fill=white!20] {?}

(T.east) edge (A.south)

(T.east) -- (A.south) node[midway, circle, draw,fill=white!20] {?} ;

\path

(F.west) edge[transform canvas={xshift=-3mm}]  (G.west)

(F.west) -- (G.west) node[transform canvas={xshift=-1.5mm}, midway, circle, draw,fill=white!20] {?} ;
(F.west) -- (G.west) node[transform canvas={xshift=-3mm},midway,draw] {?} ; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me clean that up a bit and use some nice libraries:

- `arrows.meta` for arrow tips:

  - `> = Latex`
- `chains` for an easy way to place nodes in a row:

  - `start chain`
  - `every join`
  - `join = by …`
  - nodes are automatically named `<chain name>-<n>` where `<n>` counts up, the default `<chain name>` is chain
- `positioning` (loaded by `chains`) for better positioning of nodes in relation to each other:

  - `right = of …`
  - `above = of …`
  - used by `chains` library and uses the given `node distance`
- `ext.paths.ortho` for more orthogonal path options:

  - `ortho/install shortcuts` to have access to the `-|` key that installs the [`-|` path operation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.2.2) for edges → C8 and C9
  - the `r-lr` path operation (installed via the `lr` key) → C5, C6 and C7
- `quotes` to have a nice shortcut (see `quotes mean question mark`) to place your question marks along a path

  - this places a node with a `?` along the path and a label on *that* node with the given text

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, ext.paths.ortho, quotes}
\tikzset{
  nudge   up/.style={yshift={ (#1)*2mm}}, nudge   up/.default=1,
  nudge down/.style={yshift={-(#1)*2mm}}, nudge down/.default=1,
  /utils/temp/.style={#1/.style={ortho={#1 distance={##1}},to path={r-#1(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}},
  /utils/temp/.list={rl, lr, du, ud},
  qm/.style={circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=+.15em},
  quotes mean question mark/.style={
    edge quotes mean={edge node={node[qm, label={[direction shorthands,##2]##1}]{?}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=Latex,
  box/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=3cm, align=center, minimum height=1cm},
  node distance=1.5cm and 2cm,
  start chain=going below,
  every join/.append style={->},
  quotes mean question mark
]
\foreach[count=\i from 0] \t in {Enrolment, First Year, Second year, Third year, Graduate}
  \node[on chain, box, join=by "C\i" right]{\t};
\node[box, right=of chain-3] (chain-a) {Attrition};

\path[every join, ortho/install shortcuts, ortho/middle 0 to 1]
  ([nudge down] chain-2.west) edge[lr,      near start, "C5" right]              (chain-4)
  ([nudge   up] chain-2.west) edge[lr=15mm, pos=.3,     "C6" right] ([nudge down] chain-5.west)
               (chain-3)      edge[lr=10mm, near end,   "C7" right] ([nudge   up] chain-5.west)
               (chain-2)      edge[-|,      near start, "C8" below]              (chain-a)
               (chain-3)      edge[                     "C9" below]              (chain-a)
               (chain-4)      edge[-|,      near start, "C10"below]              (chain-a)
;
\node[circle, fill, draw, above=of chain-begin, "Entry Point" right] {} edge[every join] (chain-begin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I didn't see the Entry point dot at the beginning which is why it is added at the end but that might be better anyway because otherwise we'd need to make sure there's no `C0` node.

Comment: Thank you so much @Qrrbrbirlbel